# Do I need to install jdk and jre in the same directory?

Tags: java, directory, ubuntu-16.04

I first installed `jre` version 8 on Ubuntu in this directory : `/usr/local/java` , now I want to install `Oracle JDK` version 8, do I have to install `Oracle JDK` in a directory similar to jre? And is it better to uninstall `jre`? And just install `jdk`?

Comment: Just install the JDK.  It comes with a JRE.  It's either/or.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't to choose the directory, just do:

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

It installs both `jre` and `jdk`.

If you see this error:
`E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate`

You can download the last `Oracle JDK 8` here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html#javasejdk
and perform a manual install. Be aware of the licensing terms; they may require a fee for use in production. Other vendors offering implementations of Java include Azul Systems, Adoptium/AdoptOpenJDK, RedHat/IBM, Amazon, Microsoft, SAP, Pivotal, and BellSoft.

And, [as duffymo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462818/do-i-need-to-install-jdk-and-jre-in-the-same-directory#comment119241670_67462818), the [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) contains a JRE.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer totally depends upon your use case. JRE is usually meant for higher development environments like Android. JDK is suitable for high school level code, and for running operations on-computer. Usually the software you are using for development will come with JRE if it needs one so you don't need to download it manually. So I guess it's okay to uninstall the JRE. Keep the JDK wherever you want, but if you wish to use it from the command line you need to add a JAVA_HOME variable to the system variables. Oh I think I drifted towards Windows.

Comment: If you use IDEs like Eclipse, they usually come pre-packed with JRE so you do not need to do anything manually. If they don't, however, the documentation will most probably give you directions on the same